# Есть ли альтернатива Microsoft SQL Server'у?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Имеем ГИС. Сейчас БД работает на Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
Всё это "счастье" доступно по вебу. Десятки и сотни пользователей ежедневно, в проекте пользователей будут тысячи. В предметных БД десятки таблиц, количество записей от десятков и сотен тысяч до десятков миллионов. Сотни хранимых процедур, функций и вьюшек, используются триггеры. Раз это ГИС, то работать приходится с объектами Geometry и прочими Spatial Objects, координаты и карты.

За сим вопрос: возможна ли альтернатива Microsoft SQL Server'у при таких условиях и нагрузках?

Comment: Да, PostgreSQL.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо, буду почитать. С Постгре дело имел в самом начале двухтысячных, с тех пор с ним не имел дела. Главным образом вопрос стоит в том, потянет ли этот сервер подобные объёмы быстрее или хотя бы на уровне с Микрософтом?

Comment: Вы бы сперва сформулировали, чем именно SQL Server не устраивает. Чётко, по пунктам, с количественными оценками. А то окажется, что даже повода, не то что причины, что-то менять - и той нету, кроме абстрактной хотелки...

Comment: @Akina стоимостью, наверное

Comment: @Akina В первую очередь не бесплатность решения от Microsoft. По большому, других причин нет.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, MS SQL уже приобретён. Т.е. по текущему инстансу вопроса цены - нет. Т.е. получается, что "по большому счёту", причины нет вообще никакой.

Comment: @Akina И да, и нет. Конечно sql server приобретён, но задача стоит так, чтобы при рефакторинге системы (предстоит смена версии php на 7, приведение нескольких проектов порядок в смысле кодировок, сейчас мешанина из utf8 и windows-1251, переезд на другие сервера как территориально, так и по платформам) - проще говоря, придётся всё заново написать. Хотелось бы совсем избавиться от ПК с виндой и проч. Отсюда возник и вопрос.

Comment: О! если прижать - так всё оказывается вовсе и не так, а очень даже иначе... тогда, пожалуй, соглашусь с @SergeyGornostaev. Или, как альтернатива, MySQL.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, уже читаю про PostgreSQL. В про MySQL гложет сомнение, не слышал, чтобы в нём можно было работать с geometry и выдержит ли сервер нагрузки при десятках миллионов строк в таблицах? В общем, читать ещё долго. Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: *не слышал, чтобы в нём можно было работать с geometry* [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Data Types  /  Spatial Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html). *выдержит ли сервер нагрузки при десятках миллионов строк в таблицах?* Сотня таблиц по 10kk записей - это далеко не чрезмерный объём. *уже читаю про PostgreSQL* Учтите, что во многих вопросах идеология реализации у него совсем не такая, как у SQL Server... просто для примера посмотрите, как цепляется на таблицу триггер.

Comment: как связан переезд на пхп 7 и кодировка с sql server не ясно. Несколько странно также и выбрасывать лицензию SQL сервер на ветер (не девелопер же? ). 2019й кстати доступен для линукса.

Comment: Мне во всем этом интересно, действительно ли вы готовы переписать начисто во эти "_Сотни хранимых процедур, функций и вьюшек, используются триггеры_" под другую БД.

Comment: @Mike, моя задача сейчас выяснить, возможно ли это в принципе. О трудозатратах думать - отдельная задача. И скорее всего, взвесив всё, руководство смену сервера БД отыграет. Как по мне, то оно и к лучшему, но выяснить принципиальную возможность такого перехода я должен.